# Evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,0)}\frac{\cos(xy)-1}{x^2y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

normally, I would just use substitution, since I'm pretty sure the limit does exist. However, I'm not sure if I can use substitution, since x does not equal y.

Can I use substitution, or am I thinking about this problem in the wrong way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: let $t=xy$ and work on
$$ \lim_{t\to0}\frac{\cos t-1}{t^2}. $$

Comment: Can we take the limit of t as it approaches zero because we know y=0?

Comment: Of course you can.